# Как заставить Java - машину использовать двухядерный процессор на 100%

Tags: windows, java, swt

При работе многопоточного Java + SWT - приложения процесс javaw никогда не загружает процессор более чем на 50% (процессор, соответственно, двухядерный). Проверял на ОC Windows. 50% загрузки - это реальное значение? Или ОС просто делит уровень общей загрузки CPU Java-приложением на количество "доступных процессоров"? Если реальное, то как заставить Java-машину работать "на все 100"?

Comment: Хотите 100% - делаейте хотя бы ещё один тред. Так как в Вашей программе подозреваю только один тред, то он не может загрузить более одного ядра. Ядер 2, поэтому не более 50% от общего.

Comment: Человек написал, что у него многопоточное приложение!

Comment: Так точно, в нужный момент я держу как минимум 2 потока. Но максимум, что вижу - это 60% загрузки.

Comment: Выжимку (в смысле многопоточности) из кода приведите. 

Вообще-то много ресурсов (в смысле параллельности использования CPU) может уходить на синхронизацию (не знаю, у Вас она есть ?).

Comment: Можно и в многопоточном код так написать, что он будет грузить только на 50% (например классика жанра - тред вызывает внешний метод, который синхронизированный).

Comment: а в каком режиме вы запускаете вашу JVM: client / server ? это тоже должно существенно влиять на загрузку машины.   
гуглить: java vm client vs server

Answer (score 4):

Загрузка ядер зависит от версии работающего JVM. Более-менее нормальная поддержка многоядерных процессоров работает начиная с версии Java 1.6, также имеет смысл обратить внимание на битность работающего JVM'а - x64 или x86. Если ось 64-х разрядная имеет смысл установить оба JRE поскольку в разных ситуациях могут быть задействованы разные JRE 64-х или 32-х разрядные.

Вообще скорость работы JVM в многопоточных приложениях лимитируется скоростью аллокации объектов (т.н. allocation wall) - читай проще скоростью записи в RAM - то есть бутылочное горлышко проходит там. Более подробно [читать здесь](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1640116). В общем надо сначала "расшить" эту сторону и тогда можно говорить об увеличении загрузки процессора.

Comment: если в программе один тред (и нет неявных других), то как бы java не напрягалась, загрузить более одного ядра не получится. (если только компилятор не сможет придумать, как распараллелить код)

Comment: @KoVadim я бы не был так категоричен... JVM в состоянии загрузить все ядра - просто распараллеливание будет не на уровне нитей/тредов, а на уровне процессов

Comment: На уровне процессов - тут понятно. Я думаю, если бы ТС запустил две копии своей программы, то вполне бы и на 100% загрузило бы:)

Comment: Любое приложение редко имеет 1 процесс, так что ирония неуместна :)

Comment: Вы наверно хотели сказать "один тред". А то иначе немного иронично.

Comment: Нет, я хотел сказать именно процесс :) RTFM!

Answer (score 2):

Сделал. Barmaley был прав, у меня в приложении крупные объекты ворочаются. Они просто не успевали создаваться в памяти. Сделал нормальную работу с памятью, довел макс. загрузку до 98%. Благодарю всех за помощь!